# How to debug 'Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs' exception?

Tags: windows, xaml

In my C# windows application, I get this 'Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs' when I run it in my debugger:

{Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}
{"Access is denied.\r\n"}
false
"Access is denied.\r\n"
To inspect the native object, enable native code debugging.

Does anyone has any idea how to debug that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you need to do this :

The **Unmanaged code debugging** property, available on the **Debug** page of the **Project Designer**, determines whether debugging of native code is supported. Select this option if you are making calls to COM objects, or if you start a custom program written in native code that calls your project and you need to debug the native code.

**To enable debugging of unmanaged code**

1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu,
   click Properties.
2. Click the Debug tab.
3. Select the Enable unmanaged code debugging check box.

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tdw0c6sf(v=vs.100).aspx)